# Use a View controller multiple times in navigation controller in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, twitter

I am new in iOS, I am creating a app much like twitter, I am using Storyboard for it. In this app i have a View controller class which shows the user Detail and their feeds like received messages, On click on message user can see message sender profile detail on another View controller i am using navigation controller push segue to go from user profile to message sender profile.

I want to Open further message sender profile on second View Controller on click of message

Like from A -> B -> C -> D -> E  and so on.., same as like Facebook or twitter so that the go back order is also same in navigation controller.

Comment: I don't see a question. Whats the issue?

Comment: on click of message manke  another segue to detailsViewController and so on..

Comment: i want to use a single view controller class multiple times in navigation controller. how can i do this?

Comment: Single view controller for all class? have you gone mad? even twitter facebook have multiple view controller... **I think you should learn how to go from one view controller to another using navigation**

Comment: Thanks AppleDelegate, So i have to create multiple view controller in storyboard and their related classes?

Comment: @Guri ... the same way you use different classes, make a new instance and push it on the navigation stack. If your asking questions like this you badly need to read a book on objective-c ... and object oriented programming for that matter

Comment: Fahim Parkar, Why I have create multiple view controller every time, i just want to reload data in view controller and push it in navigation controller. Can anyone suggest me how I can do this?

Comment: are you asking about how to push one view controller on top of another view controller of the same class?

Answer (score 0):

The navigation controller works as a stack, it is automatically adjusted to work the way you need.

Add navigation controllers like this:

```
UIViewController *bbp=[[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"UIViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *passcodeNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:bbp];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:passcodeNavigationController animated:YES];
  [passcodeNavigationController release];
```

Go through apple docs to get a clear idea: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html